# Using a reusable component in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I want to use a component in another component (home.html). But i get an error as :

Error: Template parse errors: 'reusable' is not a known element: 1. If 'reusable' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. 2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("[ERROR ->]

Here is my "reusable.html" file.

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-navbar>
<ion-button (click) = "onPress()">
  Logout 
</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Here is my reusable.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Toast } from '@ionic-native/toast';

@Component({
  selector: 'reusable',
  templateUrl: 'reusable.html'
})

export class ReusableComponent {

  constructor(private toast: Toast) { }

  onPress(){
    this.toast.show(`You have been logged out!`, '5000', 'center').subscribe(
      toast => {
        console.log(toast);
  });
}  
}
```

Here is my home.html file where i am using it:

```
<reusable>
  </reusable> 

<ion-content padding>
 <p> The world is your oyster. <p>
</ion-content>
```

Here is my app.module.ts file:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Can you show your module file? You probably missed to declare or export that component.

Comment: I just added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add your `component` to `declarations` array of the `module` in which it is implemented, to be used by other `components` of the same `module`. To utilize them in another `module`, you should be adding that `component` to `exports` array as well.

```
declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ReusableComponent 
  ],
```

Comment: Should be a `components module`

Comment: @core114 Yes, that point is important!

Comment: Thanks @AmitChigadani. It works!